# How to know the url from a pdf component? (Tridion2009)

Tags: pdf, tridion2009

We have some pdf as a multimedia components. And I would like to know the url before I publish the page where we are using the pdf. The component is already published.

I was trying to guess looking another examples: domain/en/multimedia/Name_pdf.pdf
But didn't work...

¿Someone knows the rule?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **lot** depends on how you are handling the multimedia component within your templates, whether you are creating variants (probably not for PDF files) and, to a certain extent, what kind of delivery environment you are using and how it is configured.

If you are trying to output a link to your published binary from a template, you should probably use the out-of-the-box functionality by outputting syntax like

```
<a href="#" tridion:href="[MMCompTcmUri]">text</a>
```

from your templates and then using the other default TBBs to publish the component and resolve the link for you.

However, in a default, standard 2009 environment, with normal publishing, you should find that your file is simply published to the file system at

```
<Publication Images Path>\<Binary Filename>
```

With the link resolving to

```
http://<Your server>/<Publication Images URL>/<Binary Filename>
```

Note:
In earlier versions of Tridion the binary filename was manipulated to include the TCM Id for uniqueness, but by 2009 this was no longer the case